# The data file size do not shrink down when delete from ravendb

Tags: ravendb

I used the following code to delete documents from RavenDB. At the bottom of Raven UI, I can see the number of documents decrease from 3,000,000 to 2,000,000. But the size of the "Data"  file does not shrink down. It is always about 100G.

```
            store.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex("Sagas/ByStarted", new IndexQuery
            {
                Query = "Started:{00010101000000 TO 20130101000000}",
            });
```

Server Build #960, Client Build #960 
Please help ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is by design. We don't give out space back to the OS by default. We keep *and reuse* that space again as needed.
If you really need to trim the file size, you would need to compact the db, but that is an offline operation.

Comment: Alex, it doesn't get any more official than this :)

Comment: Sorry, one more question though. My hard drive only has 1G left. I guess I still need to compact the db, otherwise it will be difficult to tell when the "Data" file take up all the space right?

Comment: In 960, you can compact using esentutl /d <dbname>
But I think that it needs to create temp files along the way, and 1GB may not be enough if you have 100GB db